# Haskel ghci.exe error (0xc0000142)

Tags: windows, haskell

I tried all versions of haskell from their website and installed them on my windows 10 computer but when i run ghc.exe i get the following error shown in the image:

I have tried several troubleshooting techniques but i cannot find the problem. Note that i have installed the files inside c:/ path

[image]

Comment: Why does it say `calc.exe`?

Comment: ignore it, it is an image from google, it just demonstrates the error.

Comment: Sounds like it couldn’t start a DLL it needs. You can try uninstalling and running the full installer from haskell.org. Also do step 3 here: https://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html#windows

Comment: I did that step, still i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Run the program named "WinGHCi", not "GHCi".

Comment: good, but it is not a solution to the problem, i can use notepad++ with that way anyway, there is no need to use Context